# Fiware : wilma vs steelskin

Tags: fiware, fiware-wilma

when to use wilma and when to use steelskin?

why there is no reference of steelskin in [fiware generic enablers catalogue](http://catalogue.fiware.org/enablers)?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wilma is an official FIWARE enabler.

Steelskin is not part of FIWARE, but is developed by some people that are very involved in FIWARE (from Telefonica) and is mostly compatible.

So if you want to be 100% FIWARE compliant go with Wilma. If you don't care then it may be interesting to research further on Steelskin.

Comment: I think that the Steelskin is part of FIWARE (in the sense it implements a FIWARE GE specification, i.e. the one for PEP Proxy GE), but not as a GEri but as a GEi. The GEri for PEP Proxy GE is Wilma.

Comment: For a detailed explanation about GE, GEi and GEri see: https://ask.fiware.org/question/1/what-is-a-fiware-ge-and-a-gei/